# I need to call a method inside my WallpaperService only when user has finished with selecting his preferences

Tags: android

I have a LiveWallpaper.

I need create a method inside the `WallpaperService` that has to be called **only when the user has finished** selecting all his preferences from the `PreferenceActivity`.

Please how could I do it it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved:

I send a Broadcast to the `WallpaperService` the form `onStop()` of my `PreferenceActivity`.